# JavaScript in Azure Boards

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

I need to manipulate, calculate some fields in work-items in azure DevOps. Is their any tools like JS to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do calculations within Azure DevOps UI natively with out creating a extension.

What I have done in the past is to use the Service Hooks to call a Azure Function on work item update. Then you can do what ever calculation you want and update the work item.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you elaborate that? or provide some documents or ytb links? Thanks in advance.